# Unable to get object from top hits aggregation

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I am unable to get object from response in NEST from top_hits aggregation.

```
var searchRespJson = node.SearchForDataBool<JObject>(sourceOptions);
var dailyBuckets = searchRespJson.Aggregations.DateHistogram("daily").Buckets;
var topHits = dailyBuckets.Select(z => z.TopHits("lastresult").Hits<ObjExample>()).ToList();
```

When I want to get source from topHits, it is still null as you can see bellow.
[image: Screenshot from debugging]

Here is my response from ES which is one as on the screenshot up:

```
{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 95,
    "successful": 95,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "daily": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1588291200000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "lastresult": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 4,
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "qa-reporting-2020-05",
                  "_type": "qa-reporting",
                  "_id": "49604317731477703817213013055855948409579155497894805506.0",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "MetaData": {
                      "TestStatusStr": "Passed"
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    1588365938425
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my ObjExample:

```
public class MetaData
    {
        public string TestStatusStr { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hit
    {
        public string _index { get; set; }
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public object _score { get; set; }
        public Source _source { get; set; }
        public IList<long> sort { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjExample
    {
        public IList<Hit> hits { get; set; }
    }
```

I wish to get to the Source-MetaData-TestStatusStr using NEST. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Very bad mix of property naming policies. Btw object and json matches. I have no idea. What deserializer are you using for json?

Comment: JObject or dynamic

Comment: `Newtonsoft.JSON`? Please add the information about it to the question with the code line where you perform deserealization.

Comment: Yes `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` .I have added the code line...

Comment: The types _look_ like they are mapping out parts of the API that are already taken care of by NEST, like `Hit`. The only type that needs to be implemented is the one NEST should use to deserialize the `_source` into for each hit

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to get deserialized object using `var topHits = dailyBuckets.Select(z => z.TopHits("lastresult").Documents<Source>()).ToList();` which corresponds with the correct object class per given JSON response